# Using qt debug symbols from ppa in qtCreator

Tags: ppa, qt, qt-creator, debugging

How to make use of debug symbols in qtCreator, that are installed using ppa? I use Stephan Binner "Qt 5.5.1 for /opt Trusty" packages, including packages with -dbg postfix.

Running command:

```
dpkg-query -L qt55base-dbg | grep debug | grep libQt5Core.so
```

shows that /usr/lib/debug/opt/qt55/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.5.1 is present. But I don't know how to make qtCreator to link to it using Debug configuration (using qmake and cmake).

I am sure that correct "Qt Version" is selected. Modules View in debug shows that libQt5Core is loaded from /opt/qt55/lib/libQt5Core.so.5

I tried to run:

```
source /opt/qt55/bin/qt55-env.sh
```

and launching qtCreator after. Same results.

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this just a matter of, `#include <QDebug>`? Also why are you not simply using the Ubuntu SDK?

Comment: @Akiva 

 1. AFAIK #include <QDebug> will not order linker to link to debug versions of libraries.
 2. Ubuntu SDK? You mean qt5-default in ubuntu repos? It is much older (5.2.1).

QtSDK from official site does not have debug symbols, see this [comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13926?focusedCommentId=272273&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-272273) and bugreport. Also I like to use repositories whenever possible.